# Compile Error Argument Not Optional for a collection, within a private type, in a class module

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class module named "Melted" with roughly this relevant code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type Melted
    CommonID As String
    Longdata1 As Collection
    Longdata2 As Collection
End Type
Private this As Melted

Public Property Get Longdata1() As Collection 'This line is highlighted by the debugger
    Longdata1 = this.Longdata1
End Property
Public Property Let Longdata1(ByVal value As Collection)
    Set this.Longdata1 = value
End Property

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Longdata1 = New Collection
    Set this.Longdata2 = New Collection
End Sub
```

In another module I run roughly this code, where I try to add data to the Longdata collections:

```
Private AllMelted As Object
Private CommonIDs As Collection
Public Property Get GetID() As String 'Using Get because I dont need arguments
    Dim Nextup As String
    Nextup = CommonIDs.Item(CommonIDs.Count)
    CommonIDs.Remove CommonIDs.Count
    GetID = Nextup
End Property
Public Property Get Melteds() As Object
    Melteds = AllMelted
'Only access the dictionary through this
End Property
Public Property Get Reset() As Boolean
    AllMelted = Nothing
    CommonIDs = Nothing
    Reset = True
End Property

Function ProcessRow(ByVal CurrentRow As Range) As Integer
    If Not AllMelted.Exists(CurrentRow.Cells(1).value) Then
        CommonIDs.Add CurrentRow.Cells(1).value
        Dim Currmelt As Melted
        Set Currmelt = New Melted
        Currmelt.Class_Initialize
        Currmelt.CommonID = CurrentRow.Cells(1).value
        Currmelt.Longdata1.Add CurrentRow.Cells(2).value'The error occurs here. Previous step works.
        Currmelt.Longdata2.Add CurrentRow.Cells(3).value
        AllMelted.Add CurrentRow.Cells(1).value, Currmelt
    Else
        AllMelted(CurrentRow.Cells(1).value).Longdata1.Add CurrentRow.Cells(2).value
        AllMelted(CurrentRow.Cells(1).value).Longdata2.Add CurrentRow.Cells(3).value
    End If
    ProcessRow = CommonIDs.Count
End Function

Sub Preprocess()
    AllMelted = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set CommonIDs = New Collection
    For Each Row in ActiveSheet.Rows
        Dim Progress As Integer
        Progress = ProcessRow(Row)
    Next Row
End Sub
```

The line `Currmelt.Longdata1.Add CurrentRow.Cells(2).value` never completes and I get a compile error. In the class module, the line `Public Property Get Longdata1() As Collection` gets highlighted by the debugger. Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

Just FYI, I'm going through melted data and trying to store each aggregate, as a "Melted" type, in a dictionary. If the aggregate ID is already present in the dictionary, then data in the new row is simply used to add to the collections in the "Melted" type. I made AllMelted and CommonIDs private because I want to store data in them for use in a second sub run. All of the above is part of a preprocessing step. I don't know if those parts are correct or are involved in causing the issue.

Comment: Set Longdata1 = this.Longdata1
will compile

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Thank you. I'll see if it works.